# Get Title of the Current page from Shell.html using DurandalJS/Router

Tags: knockout.js, durandal, durandal-navigation

I try to find title for the current page (navigation)... the only way that work for me was: that is a little ugly.

```
<!-- ko foreach: router.navigationModel -->
    <h1 data-bind="text: title, visible: isActive"></h1>
<!-- /ko -->
```

A better way will be this one... but I don't know the current index page

```
<!--<h1 data-bind="text: router.navigationModel()[____INDEX____].title"></h1>-->
```

Any suggestion to addressing this problem in a better way???

Comment: I like the answer provided by @gerrod in one of his comments below using `router.activeInstruction().config.title`

Answer (score 1):

Durandal's router does not store the index of the current route, it only provides the `isActive` property to check whether a a given route is active or not. So the only options is search for the `isActive` route.

Instead of using the `foreach` in your view you can create a computed in your `shell.js` which encapsultes this route finding logic:

```
currentTitle: ko.computed(function () {
    var activeRoute = ko.utils.arrayFirst(router.navigationModel(), 
         function (item) {
            return item.isActive();
    });
    if (activeRoute)
        return activeRoute.title;
})
```

And now in your `shell.html` you can just write:

```
<h1 data-bind="text: currentTitle"></h1>
```

Alternatively as [gerrod](https://stackoverflow.com/users/127497/gerrod) pointed out in a comment you can use `activeInstruction` property of the `router` from where you can get the current `config` and from there the `title`:

```
<h1 data-bind="text: router.activeInstruction().config.title"></h1>
```

Comment: You could alternatively check `router.activeInstruction().config` - this is the active route.

Comment: @gerrod thanks for the info about the `activeInstruction` I've included it in my answer.